# Validate Wysiwyg field

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I try to validate Wysiwyg field. It's hard to detec when it's empty because it auto add `<p>&nbsp;</p>` .How I can check,that Wysiwyg contain only

?

Field value can also looks like:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I mean it can contain not only 1 tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with : `content.replace(/<p>(:?&nbsp;)+<\/p>\n?/g, "").length === 0`

```js
var content = "<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\n\
<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\
<p>&nbsp;</p>"

var isEmpty = content.replace(/<p>(:?&nbsp;)+<\/p>\n?/g, "").length === 0;

console.log(isEmpty)
```

Comment: Good ansver, but `<p>&nbsp;</p>` can also contain more that 1 space, `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: between the `<p>` ? you mean multiple `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: Yes, can be `<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`